# Use of 'ask' as a verb

Tags: verbs

When I need a piece of advice, I say:

> I want an advice of you.

or

> I want to ask for your advice.

Because we "ask somebody for something" or we " ask something of somebody"

e.g. Can I ask a favour of you?/ Can I ask you a favour?

Can I say:

> I wat to ask an advice from you.
>
> I want an advice from you.

I think the structure in the first sentence is not right; and the use of the preposition 'from' in the second sentence makes it incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First, remember that **[advice](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/advice)** is not countable, so you can't say "an advice". You would normally just say "advice" or "some advice".

You compared it with the phrase "ask somebody for something", and that is a good model for the correct sentence:

> I want to ask you for some advice.
> I want to ask you for advice about...

As this [NGram graph](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ask%20for%20advice%20from%2Cask%20advice%20of%2Cask%20%2A%20for%20advice&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cask%20for%20advice%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cask%20advice%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t2%3B%2Cask%20%2A%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bask%20me%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bask%20him%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bask%20you%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bask%20them%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bask%20her%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bask%20us%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bask%20others%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bask%20anyone%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bask%20people%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bask%20someone%20for%20advice%3B%2Cc0) shows, "ask * for advice" is the most widely used, and "ask for advice from *" comes second. You can also use "ask advice of *": this form was popular in the 19th century, but now sounds quite formal and dated.

> it was usual for the bishop of a small town to ask advice of the bishop of the metropolis - *An introduction to Christianity, Joseph Sutcliffe, 1814*